# Authorization in a web application

Tags: java, spring, authorization

I am looking forward to implement authorization in one of my projects. One of the option that I found was URL,METHOD based spring security. This allow the control on the basis of ROLE. But what about that a user if having a VIEW role can view all of the resources but can't edit any resource. 
Is there any Existing framework that can provide this granularity? ,so that with a role the permissions on various resources can be applied.

Thanks

Comment: From what I understood, URL/Method is enough for you to achieve what you need. Dont give access to any of the post method for that particular role. If this is not what you need, Can you please elaborate your requirement ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below solution.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/api/resource/employee/**"
        access="hasAnyRole('MANAGER','EMPLOYEE','HR')"
        method="GET" />
<intercept-url pattern="/api/resource/employee/**"
        access="hasAnyRole('MANAGER','HR')" method="POST" />
```